# Print average of specific field of arraylist, but filter by another field

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

So I have a class car, with size and length variables.
I have created an arraylist for storing the car objects.
I would like to use a java stream to filter the list by size using lambda expression, but then calculate the average of each cars length only.
So in the code below I want to get get the average length of cars with a size greater than ten but less than thirty.

I have seen other posts on how to average an arraylist of integers etc, but this is a list of objects that contain integers
I cannot get any output, any suggestions greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import java.util.List;


public class Car {
    
        int size;
        int length;
        
        public Car (int s, int l) {
            size = s;
            length = l;
        }
    
        public int getSize() {
            return size;
        }
        
        public int getLength() {
            return length;
        }
        
    
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        ArrayList<Car> list = new ArrayList<Car>();
        Car t1 = new Car(1,5);
        Car t2 = new Car(8,6);
        Car t3 = new Car(12,9);
        Car t4 = new Car(25,12);
        
        list.add(t1);
        list.add(t2);
        list.add(t3);
        list.add(t4);
    
        
         int info = list.stream()
        .filter(l -> l.getSize() > 10 && l.getSize() <30 )
        .average(Car.getLength);
        
            }

}
```

Comment: Which part of your code do you expect to `print` anything?

Comment: I suggest you investigate `Stream#mapToInt()` -- that should get you to a collection of `int`s.

Comment: okay will check it out thanks jim

Comment: PM 77-1 i would like the .average to print the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ".average()" terminal/aggregate operation in this context is for an IntStream class.

So, instead of calling `.average(Car.getLength)` (which isn't correct syntax for method reference anyway, assuming that's what you were going for), you need something like:

```
OptionalDouble average = list.stream()
.filter(l -> l.getSize() > 10 && l.getSize() < 30)
.mapToInt(Car::getLength)
.average();

int avg;

if (average.isPresent(){
   avg = (int) average.getAsDouble();
   System.out.println(avg);
}
```

That way, once the .average() operation is hit, it is correctly being hit by an IntStream

How you deal with the case where the average value is not present (original streamed list was empty, for ex), is up to you. I didn't initialize the avg variable because I'm assuming you just need it for printing within that conditional, but if you will need it later, you will need to actually initialize it.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html

Some examples of using the average operation:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/intstream-average-in-java-with-examples/

Comment: hey thanks for the input, I tried your code but recieve the following error Type mismatch: cannot convert from OptionalDouble to int, I tried double average instead of int average and changed mapToInt to mapToDouble but no luck

Comment: @Stopdownvotingfornoreason Apologies, I have updated the answer to account for the return type of OptionalDouble.

I went ahead and initialized the avg int to -1 just as a placeholder for whatever your preference is in the situation of initializing an int, and then actually setting the value within a conditional.

Comment: I just wanted to say that works perfectly now, thanks a million, you're a life saver mate.

Comment: My pleasure, I ended up removing the initialization of the avg variable, and adding my explanation as to why.. I tried to just edit my first comment to note this, but am not able to, so figured I'd just add this here for added context as to why that part of my first comment is not relevant anymore.